# Why is this Spock Specification in Grails resulting in 'identifier of an instance of projectname.Event was altered from 1 to 2;'?

Tags: hibernate, exception, grails, integration-testing, spock

Running `test-app integration:spock` causes the following error:

> identifier of an instance of
>   projectname.Event was altered from 1
>   to 2; nested exception is
>   **org.hibernate.HibernateException**: identifier of an instance of
>   projectname.Event was altered from 1
>   to 2
>
> **org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException**:
>   identifier of an instance of
>   projectname.Event was altered from 1
>   to 2;
>
> nested exception is
>   **org.hibernate.HibernateException**: identifier of an instance of
>   projectname.Event was altered from 1
>   to 2 at
>   projectname.EventControllerSpec.save:
>   an
>   event(EventControllerSpec.groovy:74)
>
> Caused by:
>   **org.hibernate.HibernateException**: identifier of an instance of
>   projectname.Event was altered from 1
>   to 2

1. **Where does this issue stem from?**
2. **How can it be resolved?**
3. [OPTIONAL] May somebody create the Tag "[spock](https://code.google.com/p/spock/)"?

---

**from EventControllerSpec.groovy**

```
def "save: an event"() {
    given: "Constraint-conform event properties"
    def eventTitle              = "Being in Beijing"
    controller.params.title     = eventTitle
    controller.params.details   = "Details"
    controller.params.location  = "Beijing"
    controller.params.startDate = "01.09.2030"
    controller.params.startTime = "20:15"
    controller.params.endDate   = "01.09.2030"
    controller.params.endTime   = "21:45"
    controller.params.publisher = getUserObject("someuser")

    when: "I save that event"
    def result = controller.save() // THIS IS LINE #74 AS STATED IN THE ERROR

    then: "The event is successfully saved and the show-view rendered"
    controller.flash.message.args.grep(eventTitle)
    redirectArgs.action             == "show"
    redirectArgs.id                 == result.eventInstance.id
}

private User getUserObject(String name) {
    def user = User.findByUsername(name)

    if (!user) {
        user = new User()
        user.username = name
        user.email = "${name}@example.com"
        user.pw = "barbar"
        user.pwConfirmation = "barbar"
        assert user.save()
    }

    user
}
```

**from EventController.groovy**

```
def save = {
    def eventInstance = new Event()

    eventInstance.title     = params.title
    eventInstance.details   = params.details
    eventInstance.location  = params.location
    eventInstance.startDate = DateUtil.createDate(params.startDate, params.startTime)
    eventInstance.endDate   = DateUtil.createDate(params.endDate, params.endTime)
    eventInstance.publisher = session.user

    if (eventInstance.save(flush: true)) {
        flash.message = "${message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'event.label', default: 'Event'), eventInstance.title])}"
        redirect(action: "show", id: eventInstance.id)
    }
    else {
        eventInstance.errors.each { log.warn it }
        render(view: "add", model: [eventInstance: eventInstance])
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be helpful if you could post the definition of Event. Also, what database are you using for integration tests?

Comment: I tried both, MySQL and HSQLDB; How do you think the domain classes definition has influence on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What class does your Spock test extend? It should be `spock.lang.Specification` or 
`grails.plugin.spock.IntegrationSpec` rather than `grails.plugin.spock.ControllerSpec`, which is designed for unit tests.

Comment: Hi Peter, I had moved the Spec from Unit to Integration later during development (thus still extending ControllerSpec). Now, following your hint and changing to IntegrationSpec (or spock.lang.Specification) removes access to "controller" (No such property: controller for class: corilla.EventControllerSpec). I've tried several things to get it back (new ...(), Mock()), but apparently I am doing something wrong ...

Comment: Correct. IntegrationSpec does not have the 'controller' property. You have to instantiate the controller yourself and wire in any services or other Spring beans. This is standard practice for integration tests.

BTW, why do you want to use integration test for the controller? It's value is generally quite low, whereas integration tests for services that access the database are typically higher value.